# Modular Representation Theory of the generalized Quaternion group

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Hi,
here (http://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/conferences/group.actions2011/problem.session.seattle96-maybe.pdf/ Conjuncture 3.6) i read that the indecomposables of the generalized Quaternion group,which has tame representation type,are still not classified.
Is this still the case and if yes what do we know about the representation theory of those groups?
Thanks for the help

Comment: This is still open, yes.